# Get public data member from script of another transform's child

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a gameObject 'gm' which has a script. That script has a reference to Transform parentFoo, and needs to access a non-static, public int 'x', which exists and is defined in a script attached as a component to multiple children 'bar', which are all children of parentFoo. I'm then trying to throw all these ints into a list, but the issue is with actually getting them. What's the simplest way to get this done?

The following code demonstrates what I'm trying to get done, but it doesn't work at all.

```
 //defined in UnityEditor:
 public Transform fooParent;

 void blah () {
                 List<int> list = new List<int>();

         for (int i = 0; i < fooParent.childCount; i++) {
             Transform tempChild = Players.GetChild(i);
             list.Add (tempChild.x);
         } 
 }
```

Any theoretical discussion on why and how your answer works is more than welcome :D ("teach a man how to fish...")

EDIT: specifying title, copied text to stackoverflow; removed link from Unity Answers b.c. question was fully addressed here

Comment: At least copy/paste the content of your question.

Comment: sure, I'll do that right now

Comment: ... is this a bad question somehow? I modified my original issue to make it as generic and useful as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New Code:

```
public Transform fooParent;

public void blah () {
    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < fooParent.childCount; i++) {
        Transform tempChild = fooParent.GetChild(i);
        list.Add (tempChild.gameObject.GetComponent<ScriptName>().x);
    } 
}
```

This is because `.GetChild` returns a transform so from there you must use `.gameObject` to get the GameObject that that transform is attached to. From there you can access the components attached to that gameobject (Scripts, Transforms, etc...) by using `.GetComponent<>()` where inside the <> brackets you input the name of the component (in this case the script) you want to access. Now in control of the script you can access its variables by using `.variableName`. Lastly the `void blah` should be `public void blah`. Unless of course you want it to be a private or static method.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! I'd give you a +1 as well, but the downvotes from this question pushed me under 15 reputation :'(

Comment: Ah man dont worry, SO is a tough crowd. Good luck with your project!